# Deconstructing javascript script

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm new to javascript and I am trying to destruct the following so I can understand it. I can't seem to find the answer on the web. Is anyone able to help?

```
$("#modal-add-person").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var personId = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
            $('#modal-add-person-hidden').val(personId);
            $('#modal-add-person-id-text').html(personId);
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the above code does?

Comment: Yes, in general, I don't know much about javascript, but a short explanation would really help me finish the rest of my current project. I can't find a suitable answer on the web - I was hoping someone a little more experienced in Javascript/Jquery would be able to tell me what this does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code you have [eventHandler](https://api.jquery.com/on/) on `$("#modal-add-person")` .

It means that somewhere in you global code you are triggering `'show.bs.modal'` event on

`$("#modal-add-person")` like this

`$("#modal-add-person").trigger('show.bs.modal')`

The function that is 2nd parameter of `on` function is eventHandler function that receive eventObject.

```
function (e) {
            var personId = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
            $('#modal-add-person-hidden').val(personId);
            $('#modal-add-person-id-text').html(personId);
        }
```

It use [relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.relatedTarget) property of event object and extract `data-id` attribute from it.

```
            var personId = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
```

After it set that value in  `$('#modal-add-person-hidden')` - I guess it is hidden input.

```
            $('#modal-add-person-id-text').html(personId);
```

And last thing it's do draw the value in `$('#modal-add-person-id-text')` element.

```
            $('#modal-add-person-id-text').html(personId);
```

And also you should look at jQuery reference for elements, selectors and etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#modal-add-person").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
```

'show.bs.modal' would be a event in html as a click is. So the above statement means on 'show.bs.modal' of an element with id modal-add-person ("anythig appended with a # means it is an id of a html element.") execute the steps in the function (e) where e seems to be another html element.

```
var personId = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
```

Get the attribute 'data-id' from the element passed in e.(For example if it was attr('id') it would return the id of the element passed to personid )

```
$('#modal-add-person-hidden').val(personId);
```

Set the html element with id "modal-add-person-hidden" by the value in personId

```
$('#modal-add-person-id-text').html(personId);
```

Set the element's (where id = modal-add-person-id-text) inner html with personId
});

> note: '#' stand for id of the html element '.' stands for class of the
>   element or you can give the tag as it is, for example "input" means
>   all elements with input tag

Hope this helps. Please let me know if this was helpful.